# Problem with Manipulate+Plot

Tags: plotting, manipulate

[Here's an image of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8NB4.png). PlotMe is just a variable I use to store an equation. It is shown in Out[1002]. When I use Output(1002) in In(1003) it works as expected.

However when I just use PlotMe in place of %, it simply doesn't show it. What's going on? I think it's something really simple I'm not understanding but my knowledge of Mathematica has a lot of holes in it.

The NB file for this is located [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1euFTJo44yrKG_vvF3tECgnyeeE8hXUpu/view?usp=sharing). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a scoping issue. The control variables inside the [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) are not the same as those in the definition of `PlotMe` unless you define `PlotMe` with explicit arguments. As a general rule, it is good practice to always make a function's arguments explicit. Look in the "Possible Issues" section of the documentation for `Manipulate`.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Ω = 120;
Ωm = 1 + Ω/100;
Ele = 140;
EleAdv = 50;
p[x_] := 1 + x/100
q[x_] := If[x >= 100, 1.5, x/100*0.5 + 1]
GrimHarp = {{GH, 2400, 
    0, Ωm If[HP >= 25, (HP/(60.4 - 15))^2.9 + 2.1, 0], 
    0, Ωm 10, 0, 0, 0}};
TiaGun = {{TG, 3050, Ωm 16, 
    0, Ωm 7.5 ((1 + 2 (1 - HP/100)) (1 - HP/100)), 0, 0, 0, 
    0}};
WeapGrid = MatrixForm[Join[GrimHarp, TiaGun, 1]];
AdjGrid = {
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NormAdj, 0, EleAdj + EleAdv}
  };
FnlGrid = WeapGrid[[1, All, 1]].WeapGrid[[1, All, 
     Range[2, Length[WeapGrid[[1, 1]]]]]] + AdjGrid[[1]];
NormAdj = 0;
EleAdj = 0;
PlotMe[HP_, GH_, TG_] = 
 Times @@ MapAt[q, MapAt[p, FnlGrid, {{2}, {3}, {4}, {6}, {7}, {8}}], 5]

(* 3/2 (1 + (44 TG)/125) (2400 GH + 3050 TG) (1 + 
   0.165 (1 + 2 (1 - HP/100)) (1 - HP/100) TG) If[22 GH >= 100, 1.5, 
  1/100 (22 GH) 0.5 + 1] (1 + 
   11/500 GH If[HP >= 25, (HP/(60.4 - 15))^2.9 + 2.1, 0]) *)

Manipulate[
 Plot[PlotMe[HP, GH, TG], {HP, 0, 100}],
 {GH, Range[5]}, {TG, Range[5]}]
```

[image]